# How to switch wordpress post status between publish and schedule in MySQL?

Tags: posts, publish, scheduled-posts

I am writing a program to switch a post between publish and schedule

For a scheduled post, I try to set `post_status` from future to publish, and set a past time to `post_date` and `post_date_gmt`, but the post still not be published

For a published post, I try to set `post_status` from publish to future, and set a future time to `post_date` and `post_date_gmt`, this time the post will disappear from the website, but after the future time I set, the post still not be published.

How to switch post status in MySQL?

Comment: Does it really have to be done in MySQL via raw SQL queries? A call to the REST API would do just as fine, and even trigger all the relevant hooks actions and queries for plugin compatibility

Comment: Also keep in mind that you'll be bypassing the caching layers, invalidating object and page caches, meaning you could encounter other issues